# When I was developing a Google plug-in, an error occurred during front-end and back-end interaction

Tags: javascript

I have a question when i dev chrome extensions
use React
this is the log handler in background.js and BackgroundConsole is no error
the loggerList is async

```
interface ILog {
  date: string;
  level: 'debug' | 'info' | 'warn' | 'error';
  msg: string;
}  
static loggerList: string= []
static async loggerLists(log: ILog[]) {
    this.setLogList().then(async (res) => {
      await res
      console.log(res);
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (request.type === 'log') {
          sendResponse({
            log: res
          })
        }
        return true
      })
    })
  };
  static async setLogList() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this.loggerList)
    })
  }
```

this is the popup.js when i use callback receive args

```
  const [logList, setlogList] = useState([])
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'log'
  }, res => {
    setlogList(res.log)
    console.log(res, res.log, '1111111111111');
    //PopupConsole is endless loop to console.log(res, res.log, '1111111111111')
  })
```

this is the new code with pupup.js

```
  const [logList, setlogList] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "log" }, res => {
    console.log(res);
    setlogList(res.log)
  }), [])
      <Modal title="Basic Modal" visible={isModalVisible} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
        {
          logList.map((val: any) => {
            { JSON.stringify(val) }
            // return (
            <>
              <p>{val.date}</p>
              <p>{val.level}</p>
              <p>{val.msg}</p>
              <p>{val}</p>
            </>
            // )
          })
        }
      </Modal>
```

[this is show page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRePs.png)

Comment: Wrap your `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` call in `useEffect`

Comment: useEffect(() => {
      setlogList(res.log)
    }, [])   when i use useEffect  Error handling response: Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional  
helpful warnings.    but my package.json     "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",

Comment: no... `useEffect(() => chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"log"}, res => { setlogList(res.log) }))`

Comment: okay let me try……  I'm a rookie O(∩_∩)O

Comment: If you haven't checked it out already, please see the linked duplicate at the top of your post for details

Comment: i see that, but when i use useEffect  it still wrong...  hhh

Comment: I don't know which part went wrong

Comment: Is it still an infinite loop or do you have a new problem? Please also update the code in your question to match what you're currently working with

Comment: Trouble you to take a look